# Creating django ImageField that is derived from another ImageField in django Models

Tags: python, django, image, django-models, watermark

I am creating a django Project where I had Stored a Picture(Image) in database using ImageField as...

```
original_pic = models.ImageField()
```

Also, I want to Store an Image which will Contain the Same Picture(Image)
as `original_pic` with Watermark in another ImageField as..

```
watermark_pic = models.ImageField(default=watermarkImage())
```

In short, I just want to Apply Algorithm on `original_pic` and save the result in `watermark_pic` using django models

Algorithm(Logic) for Applying Watermark to image is as follows...

```
def watermarkImage(filename, text, color, fontfamily):
    image = Image.open(filename).convert('RGBA')
    imageWatermark = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(imageWatermark)
    width, height = image.size
    font = ImageFont.truetype(fontfamily, int(height / 20))
    textWidth, textHeight = draw.textsize(text, font)
    x = width / 5
    y = height / 6
    draw.text((x, y), text, color, font)
    return Image.alpha_composite(image, imageWatermark)
```

Note: I know the Algorithm for Applying watermark on Image.

Comment: Is **`original_pic`** and **`watermark_pic`** are in **same model**? or in diffferent model?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Yes, They are in Same model

Comment: Why would you do that? It will generate **same copy** of the image..right? Is that you needed?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge No, I don't want the same copy, I want a copy of image with a Watermark added on it.That is, `watermark_pic` will contain the Copy of `original_pic` with watermark on it...

Comment: can you add the logic of doing watermark?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Check out Edits for Logic of  Adding Watermark to image

Comment: did you check my answer/

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes I did, Now I am trying to do that for watermarking instead of rotating Image. It raises Some Errors in save method

Comment: save the image in `watermarkImage()` function. and use the file name as in my example

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge will you please edit your with My Logic of Adding watermark instead of simply rotating the Image....

Comment: will that work for you? did you check? anyway , updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you watermark logic looks like. You could do it by overriding the **`save()`** method. Anyway, I made a simple working **image rotation** example for you.

```
from PIL import Image


def rotate_image(image_fp):
    im = Image.open(image_fp)
    rotate = im.rotate(45)
    filename = "rotated_" + image_fp.name
    rotate.save(filename)
    return filename


class MyBaseImageModel(models.Model):
    # your model
    original_pic = models.ImageField()
    watermark_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            rotate_img_name = rotate_image(self.original_pic)
            self.watermark_pic = rotate_img_name
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When you create the image, you dont want to put any values for `watermark_pic`

**UPDATE**

```
def watermarkImage(filename, text, color, fontfamily):
    image = Image.open(filename).convert('RGBA')
    imageWatermark = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(imageWatermark)
    width, height = image.size
    font = ImageFont.truetype(fontfamily, int(height / 20))
    textWidth, textHeight = draw.textsize(text, font)
    x = width / 5
    y = height / 6
    draw.text((x, y), text, color, font)
    my_img = Image.alpha_composite(image, imageWatermark)
    my_img.save('water_'+filename.name)
    return 'water_'+filename.name

class MyBaseImageModel(models.Model):
    # your model
    original_pic = models.ImageField()
    watermark_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            rotate_img_name = watermarkImage(your args)
            self.watermark_pic = rotate_img_name
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have Tried it, It works Perfectly while rotating Image,but  I am getting the following error while trying to add Watermark Logic... `'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'` when save() method is invoked. Did u also got Some Issues Like it?

Comment: still have some errors `must be str, not ImageFieldFile`

Comment: few edits again...use `filename.name` instead of `filename` (updated the answer)

Comment: Hey Jerin I almost got what I was Expecting..... Thanks a Lot..... Now the only problem is that Image of `watermark_pic` is not stored in /media which I had set default for Storing all Images and Uploads.....Thanks again

Comment: The tricky part is, change the `'water_'+filename.name` to an ***Absolute path*** to the `MEDIA_URL` directory